# Конвертация массивов

Tags: массивы, консоль, c++

Добрый день, коллеги. Подскажите пожалуйста нубу. 
Пользователь вводит в консольке 9 цифр, каждую из которых нужно умножить на n. Я посчитал нужным что цифры нужно записывать в массив char.

Проблема в том что  я пытаюсь конвертировать char в int.

```
int i = atoi(chr);
int test;
test = i * 6;
cout << test;
```

И, собственно, что дальше делать не догоняю. Ведь в test получается целое число, а как его разбить на составные и перемножить каждую цифру?

Спасибо)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int num;
char buf[100];

cin >> num;
sprintf(buf, "%d", num);   
// Получили что-то вроде "123123123"
for (int i = 0; buf[i] != 0; i++)
{
  int digit = buf[i] - '0';

  // Тут надо что-то делать если digit * n > 9
  buf[i] = digit * n + '0';
}
cout << atoi(buf);
```

Comment: Спасибо)

    char buf[100];

А зачем так много? С запасом?)

Comment: Да просто бывает всякая ерунда, текстовое представление double, занимающее 50 символов... По-хорошему, надо использовать _snprintf(... sizeof(buf)), тогда можно и сэкономить :) , 12 байт оставить

Comment: Спасибо) И последний вопрос)

Можно ли запретить (проверить) пользователю вводить все кроме цифр? Скажем:

    string type_id = typeid(num).name();

тупо сравнивая строки?)

Comment: Это уже стоит задать как отдельный вопрос